# NSUserDefaults objectIsForcedForKey with a nested dictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, plist

Currently I am using `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectIsForcedForKey: @"TestKey"];` to verify whether the key is managed or not.

This works great for a plist that would have each key on the list

```
 <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>Test</key>
       <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
 </plist>
```

but when I use nested dictionaries - the function can't seem to see that the object is being managed

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>TestKey1</key>
       <integer>1</integer>
       <dict>
            <key>Dictionary2</key>
            <dict>
              <key>TestKey3</key>
              <string>testkey3_value</string>
           </dict>
       </dict>
    </dict>
 </plist>
```

When I attempt to do something like `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectIsForcedForKey: @"TestKey3"];` It doesn't seem to realize that it is being managed

Answer (score 0):

Your defaults domain does not include a key named `"TestKey3"`. The dictionary containing that key is one of your own, and is not managed by `NSUserDefaults`. Therefore, `NSUserDefaults`'s APIs will not be able to see '"TestKey3"`.